# Binomial Expansion confirmation

Tags: binomial-theorem

I would like some confirmation that I have done the following binomial expansion to two terms correctly, here is what I have got:

I have to approximate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+a^2-2racos\theta}}$ for $r>>a$

I transformed it into this: $\frac{1}{r}(\frac{a^2-2arcos\theta}{r^2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Then using the formula $(1+x)^\alpha=1+\alpha x...$

I get this: $\frac{1}{r}(1-\frac{a^2-2arcos\theta}{2r^2})$

Is this correct or where have I gone wrong?

Comment: After "I transformed this" the right step is $$\frac{1}{r}\left(1+\frac{a^2-2 (a r) \cos (t)}{r^2}\right)^{-1/2}$$

Comment: the result is correct $$\frac{1}{r}\left(1-\frac{a^2-2ar \cos\theta}{2r^2}\right)$$

Comment: Ok thanks for checking that out